# How can I update a slider via updateSliderInput when also loading rhandsontable in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

it seems to me that if I use a rhandsontable in a shiny app it creates a problem with the normal way to update a slider with updateSliderInput. In the example below the click of the button should update the slider (and it does when not using a rhandsontable in the same app). Instead it somehow creates a new text field?

Is this a bug in rhandsontable or am I doing something wrong? Any help/workaround would be very much appreciated!

In case this is a bug of rhandsontable is there an alternative I can use in a shiny app to have a spreadsheet like table where data can be copied in via copy/paste from excel? It does not need to be reactive, I am fine to have a button to update the computations in the shiny app with the data. Maybe a jquery spreadsheet that can be loaded into shiny with a button?

Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("testslider","Test",0,10,5),
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")  
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                    small = letters[1:10],
                    dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    return(rhandsontable(DF))
  })
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    updateSliderInput(session,inputId = "testslider" ,value = 10,
                      min = 0, max = 10, step = 0.1)
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

hereis a picture of what happens of the field that is created when I click the button:
[image]

Comment: I cant reproduce the problem as all works fine for me

Comment: What is your `sliderinput` for?

Comment: Try updating the shiny version

Comment: @PorkChop thanks for trying out. Because it worked for you I updated all packages but that did not fix it. But in the process I found out that the problem is only in the Rstudio viewer window and not in the web browser. Therefore maybe it will not be a problem when publishing the app.

Comment: there are no error within javascript console either,  nor new div is created upon click